# verbnet definitions for senses

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

```
import nltk 
from nltk.corpus import verbnet 

metaphor1 = " I run a race" 
for word,pos in nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(metaphor1)):
   initial = metaphor1.split
   if 'V' in pos: #Another way to focus on only verbs
        verbs.append(word)
print (verbs)

for word in verbs:
    final = [sense for sense in vn.classids(word)]
    print (final)
```

The code above will print out

```
['run']
['meander-47.7', 'preparing-26.3-1', 'run-51.3.2', 'swarm-47.5.1-1']
```

The first list is the verb that is identified in the sentence "I run a race" and the second list is the list of senses correlating to that word.

I need to find a way to determine the words correlating each of the given senses. I know that verbnet and wordnet have similarities so is there a function similar to wordnet's .definition(). I'm pretty sure there is a function that returns the words associated with the given sense

Answer (score 2):

```
verbnet.lemmas('meander-47.7')
```

returns

['cascade', 'climb', 'crawl', 'cut', 'drop', 'go', 'meander', 'plunge', 'run', 'straggle', 'stretch', 'sweep', 'tumble', 'turn', 'twist', 'wander', 'weave', 'wind', 'range', 'swerve', 'veer']

See [docs](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/lope.linguistics.ntu.edu.tw/courses/python4nlp/week6-2.Working.with.Lexical.Data.2.ipynb#VerbNet).

Comment: This returns a list of verbs that could have the sense looked for. However I am looking for words that would be highly used with the given context of the sense.